# Import a csv file in Bo magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, csv

We have prepared a script that convert the csv of  product that belong to our customer then we converted to the format that magento accepted (mapping of attributs with some condition on attributs to have configurable product) but when i import the csv i get errors :
Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.

```
Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process: Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report
1. Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101 Checked rows: 101, checked entities: 101, invalid rows: 100, total errors: 100
```

***i found the errors that say : the "x", y , z attributes are invalid***

and some times i get this error:

```
Duplicates found in column names: array ( 0 => 'sku', 1 => 'store_view_code', 2 => 'attribute_set_code', 3 => 'product_type', 4
=> 'categories', 5 => 'product_websites', 6 => 'name', 7 => 'description', 8 => 'short_description', 9 => 'weight', 10 => 'product_online', 11 => 'tax_class_name', 12 => 'visibility', 13 => 'price', 14 => 'special_price', 15 => 'special_price_from_date', 16 => 'special_price_to_date', 17 => 'url_key', 18 => 'meta_title', 19 => 'meta_keywords', 20 => 'meta_description', 21 => 'base_image', 22 => 'base_image_label', 23 => 'small_image', 24 => 'small_image_label', 25
=> 'thumbnail_image', 26 => 'thumbnail_image_label', 27 => 'swatch_image', 28 => 'swatch_image_label', 29 => 'created_at', 30 => 'updated_at', 31 => 'new_from_date', 32 => 'new_to_date', 33 => 'display_product_options_in', 34 => 'map_price', 35 => 'msrp_price', 36 => 'map_enabled', 37 => 'gift_message_available', 38 => 'custom_design', 39 => 'custom_design_from', 40 => 'custom_design_to', 41 => 'custom_layout_update', 42 => 'page_layout', 43 => 'product_options_container', 44 => 'msrp_display_actual_price_type', 45 => 'country_of_manufacture', 46 => 'additional_attributes', 47 => 'qty', 48 => 'out_of_stock_qty', 49 => 'use_config_min_qty', 50 => 'is_qty_decimal', 51 => 'allow_backorders', 52 => 'use_config_backorders', 53 => 'min_cart_qty', 54 => 'use_config_min_sale_qty', 55 => 'max_cart_qty', 56 => 'use_config_max_sale_qty', 57 => 'is_in_stock', 58 => 'notify_on_stock_below', 59 => 'use_config_notify_stock_qty', 60 => 'manage_stock', 61 => 'use_config_manage_stock', 62 => 'use_config_qty_increments', 63 => 'qty_increments', 64 => 'use_config_enable_qty_inc', 65 => 'enable_qty_increments', 66 => 'is_decimal_divided', 67 => 'website_id', 68 => 'related_skus', 69 => 'related_position', 70 => 'crosssell_skus', 71 => 'crosssell_position', 72 => 'upsell_skus', 73 => 'upsell_position', 74
=> 'additional_images', 75 => 'additional_image_labels', 76 => 'hide_from_product_page', 77 => 'bundle_price_type', 78 => 'bundle_sku_type', 79 => 'bundle_price_view', 80 => 'bundle_weight_type', 81 => 'bundle_values', 82 => 'bundle_shipment_type', 83 => 'configurable_variations', 84 => 'configurable_variation_labels', 85 => 'associated_skus', 86 => '', 87
=> '', )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: and what is your question? how are we supposed to help you with this

Comment: thanks for your replay the question is clear why do i have those errors any idea please

Comment: if someone tried  to import a csv he will immediately understand this issue

Comment: "Duplicates found in column names" 86 and 87 and both empty and therefor duplicates

Comment: please provide one entry from the CSV that fails

Comment: "Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value"

Comment: Now i am getting this erreors when i tried to import again We can't find required columns: sku.
Column names: "sku "store_view_code" "attribute_set_code" "product_type" "categories" "product_websites" "name" "short_description" "weight" "visibility" "price" "url_key" "ap_feuilles_intr" "cab" "color" "format_pdt" "marque_pdt" "mg_feuilles_intr" "nbre_pages_pdt" "nbre_pieces_par_caisse" "reglure_pdt" "style_couv" "type_pap_couv" "additional_attributes" "qty" "is_in_stock" "website_id" "configurable_variations" "configurable_variation_labels" "associated_skus"" are invalid

Comment: It will be the file format. Excel plays up sometimes. Try to use "Apache Open Office Calculator" and make sure your encoding and delimiters are set correctly.

Comment: and what is the correct delimiters and encoding

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to the same problem you were having.   I was working in Excel and saving the page with the column headers and data as a CSV file.   What I did not see was that Excel must have had a space or something in the last two unused columns and when the file was saved as a CSV file it created two additional comma delimited fields with nothing in them.   The "duplicates" that were found during the validation were only the last two fields both being blank.  You can see 86=> and 87=> above are blank.
Now before I "Save As", UTF-8, I select all the valid columns and that insures there is no "blank" columns to fail the validation.   In addition, I open the resultant CSV file with Notepad++, select Encoding on the top menu, select Encode in UTF-8 (no BOM) then Save.
That solved my problem, hopefully yours as well.

Comment: thanks for your replay :)